# Simple Alert Bootbox acknowledgement and exit of code

Tags: bootbox

I am looking for a very simple bootbox.alert alert/exit and I am not able to stop the code from executing after the acknowledgment.   Also what I don't get is that I have four of these and they report empty from the bottom and work backup to the first one.

```
      if (sireid == ""){
            bootbox.alert("You must select a sire!", function(){ exit(); });        
     }
     if (damnid == ""){
            bootbox.alert("You must select a dam", function(){ exit();  });
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why finding a solution for something so simple was so difficult.

My code was exiting but unlike the javascript alert box that closes this one you have to explicitly hide.

SOlVED:

```
  if (sireid == ""){
        bootbox.alert("You must select a sire!", function(){ 
         $('.bootbox.modal').modal('hide');
        exit();});      
    }
```